# Cannot add php code to a variable?

Tags: php, file

I am trying to create a PHP file each time a user registers my website. I use the following code to create the file in my `register.php` :

The thing is, my create file function works but the variable `$data` doesn't give any result. When I run that `$data` as a single variable in a different PHP file it still doesn't work.

What did I do wrong about setting the variable.

```
    // STARTING to create a file
    $my_file = "$username.php";
    $handle = fopen("give/$my_file", 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);

    //----------- BEGINNING OF THE PHP DATA TO WRITE TO NEW FILE ----------
    $data = "<? 
require('../config.inc.php');
$damned_user = $username;
if ( $_COOKIE['damn_given'] != TRUE ) {
$sql = mysql_query(\"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$damned_user' LIMIT 1\");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1){
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        // $row['field'];
        $damned_user_id = $row['id'];
        if($_SESSION['id'] == $damned_user_id) {
        } else {
        $taken = $row['taken_damns'];
        $taken_damns = $taken + 1;
        $taking_sql = \"UPDATE users SET taken_damns='$taken_damns' WHERE username='$damned_user' \";
        if (mysql_query($taking_sql)) {
            setcookie(\"damn_given\", TRUE, time()+3600*24);
            $date = date(\"Y-m-d H:i:s\");

            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $damns_table = \"INSERT INTO damns (id, from_ip, user_damned, when_damned) VALUES ('','$ip','$damned_user','$date') \";
                if ( mysql_query($damns_table)) {

                }   else {
                    echo \"Couldn't save damn to damns table in database!\";
                }
            if ( $_SESSION['logged'] == TRUE ) {
                $session_id = $_SESSION['id'];
                $giving_sql = \"UPDATE users SET given_damns='$taken_damns' WHERE id='$session_id'\";

                if ( mysql_query($giving_sql ) ) {

                }   else {
                    echo ('Error giving damn!');
                }
            } 
        }
        else 
        {
            die (\"Error taking damn!\");
        }
        }
    }   else {
        die(\"Error first sql!\");
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />
    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/_common.css\" />
    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/_col_white.css\" />
    <link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"/favicon.ico\" />    <title>DamnIt.tk - Damned!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=\"main\">
    <div class=\"center\"><a href=\"/\"><img src=\"/_bnr_white.png\" style=\"width: 500px; height: 100px;\" alt=\"DamnIt Banner\" /></a></div>
    <table class=\"tmid\" style=\"width: 100%;\"><tr>
                    <td class=\"center\" style=\"width: 25%;\"><a href=\"/profile\">Profile</a></td>
            <td class=\"center\" style=\"width: 25%;\"><a href=\"/options\">Options</a></td>
            <td class=\"center\" style=\"width: 25%;\"><a href=\"/stats\">Stats</a></td>
            <td class=\"center\" style=\"width: 25%;\"><a href=\"/logout\">Log out</a></td>
            </tr></table>   <h1>Give a Damn</h1>
        <? 
if ( isset($_COOKIE['damn_given'])) {
    ?>
        <h2>You have already given a Damn to <? echo $damned_user ?> today!</h2><h3>Couldn't damn - try again tomorrow.</h3>    
        <?
}
elseif ( $_SESSION['id'] == $damned_user_id ) {
    ?>
        <h2>You cannot damn yourself!</h2>
        <?
}    else{ ?> <h2>Damn given!</h2><h3>You have given a Damn to <? echo $damned_user ?>.</h3> <? } ?>
</div></body>
</html>"; 

    //------- END OF PHP WHICH MUST BE WRITTEN TO NEW FILE ---------
    fwrite($handle, $data);
    fclose($handle);
    // finished with the file
```

Comment: You are **very** vunerable towards SQL injection. Everyone can change their cookies. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: To understand why creating PHP files dynamically like this is a bad idea, imagine what happens when you need to fix a bug in that generated code, or add additional features. You have a database anyway, so you can read from that whatever needs to be different on different pages, using a single copy of the    PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try NOWDOC:

```
$data = <<<'END'
Your PHP code here
END;
```

This will allow for any string, without need for escaping.

However, please consider what you're doing very carefully!

Also... you wouldn't happen to be trying to rip off this site of mine, would you? http://giveadamn.co.uk/

[image: Give a damn!]
<sub>(source: [giveadamn.co.uk](http://giveadamn.co.uk/image/Kolink.jpg))</sub>

Because if so, you're doing it wrong. `.htaccess`, mate ;)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule give/(.*) give.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Im testing my php skills. It has been 4 years.

Comment: I'm not mad or anything, I'm just curious because you have code that references giving damns and you're trying to produce the same URL as mine (`/give/USERNAME`) to make it work, it made me wonder.

Comment: Yes the .htaccess :D too complicated for me it also asks for give.php when i enter. Your error reporting gives suggestions.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I'd register for that, but I don't give a damn ;)

Comment: @TheBlueDog It's actually kinda reassuring that almost 43,000 damns have been given to me XD

Comment: There is also some HTML code. How can i add it to `<<<'END'    END;` ?

Comment: @user3527379 You can literally put whatever you like inside the NOWDOC area.

Comment: Still couldn't define the variable. Can you please try it with my code?

Comment: I'd really rather *not* help you with this. ***You are doing it wrong.*** There should *never* be a need to write PHP to a file from within PHP (except in extremely rare circumstances). You would be much better off using the simple `.htaccess` I gave you, or even just use `copy` to copy the file from a known version to its destination!

Comment: MEGAYENA7, but shh ;)

Comment: Is it possible that you somehow contact with me i think i have so much to learn from you. [link](http://facebook.com/0zankurt) email: ozankurt2@gmail.com

Comment: `RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$

RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteRule give/(.*) give.php?user=$1 [L]` is my .htaccess right?

Comment: I'd move the `give/` rule before the `Cond` lines (because you want it processed first), but otherwise that seems right.

Comment: Can i atleast have an answer for my previos comment. :) And It worked ty so much!

Comment: Is it all same with the images? You create the image each time?

Comment: No, I use `RewriteRule` to send you to `image.php`, which uses GD to generate the image and return it.

Comment: can i have the RewriteRule code i dont know htaccess well :( and please tell me a way to contact you: [link](http://facebook.com/0zankurt)